# Do Aggregation with Slick

Tags: scala, slick, scalaquery

My database structure looks like this:

id   | content

I what to get the **entry** with max id (not just id).

I read the answer [How to make aggregations with slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191057/how-to-make-aggregations-with-slick), but I found there is no `first` method in the statement: `Query(Coffees.map(_.price).max).first`. How to do that now?

What if I need the `content` of the item with the max `id`?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve another column, you could do something like the following. The below example calculates the `max` of one column, finds the row with that maximum value, and returns the value of another column in that row:

```
val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]

val mostExpensiveCoffeeQuery =
  for {
    maxPrice <- coffees.map(_.price).max.result
    c <- maxPrice match {
      case Some(p) => coffees.filter(_.price === p).result
      case None => DBIO.successful(Seq())
    }
  } yield c.headOption.map(_.name)

val mostExpensiveCoffee = db.run(mostExpensiveCoffeeQuery)
// Future[Option[String]]
```

Alternatively, to return a full `Coffees` object:

```
val mostExpensiveCoffeeQuery =
  for {
    ...
  } yield c.headOption

val mostExpensiveCoffee = db.run(mostExpensiveCoffeeQuery)
// Future[Option[Coffees]]
```